# Upgrade to 15.04. Now asks for private key password at boot

Tags: boot, password, 15.04

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04 and when I boot I now get a question before the login screen that asks me for my private key password. I didn't quite now what this password was so I've tried several different ones and after entering any value it goes away and I can login. What is the program asking me for a password?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of this  would help us help you determine what the program is asking you for a password prior to the login screen. Please take one, upload the image to a hosting service like http://imgur.com and [edit] your question to include the link. Have you tried storing the password for your network login?

Comment: The only reference to this text I could find is with OpenVPN: https://gist.github.com/jaytaylor/1337457  and a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1374782 See #7. Please add yourself to the affected people. It has a "high" status so the more people are affected ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Workaround from the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1374782). [#5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1374782/comments/5):

> I use it as Client and have deactivated autostart   AUTOSTART="none"
>
> I start it manually, when i need the VPN. In prevuse version, the
>   startscript asked for the password.
>
> Regards Franz

So disable the autostart option in the openvpn config file  (`/etc/default/openvpn`) and it will ask for it when you start it manually.

---

Another method from comment [#8](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1374782/comments/8)

> I ended up rebuilding from source with `--enable-systemd=no;` that made it work again.

---

And you can also reboot into Grub and pick the "upstart" option so you revert back to the old method instead of using systemd.

Comment: @hiflyer if I was you I would remove the 2nd part, make a new question so people can focus on that and accept this one for the part that got answered (that is the way AU works best).

Comment: I set AUTOSTART="none" and that removes the prompt. Thanks!

Comment: I moved the second part to a separate issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/615320/connect-button-grayed-out-in-802-1x-authentication-dialog