# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 with home encryption on a NVMe SSD

Tags: 16.04, encryption, ssd, thinkpad, nvme

On a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 4th Generation installing Ubuntu 16.04 with home encryption enabled I ran into the same problem as described here: [After new Ubuntu 15.04 installation, startup asks for password even though no disk encryption was set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616663/after-new-ubuntu-15-04-installation-startup-asks-for-password-even-though-no-di#)

I tried to solve it using the proposed answers, however, there is no `/dev/disk/by-id` only:

- `by-partlabel`
- `by-partuuid`
- `by-uuid`

Fstab tells me the following information

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=a7a2ee5e-14a7-423a-b32d-7f73bc076ce6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=F2B1-8BBE  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
#UUID=41826f3b-d376-4e1e-9ce6-0370b1b9969d none            swap    sw              0       0
```

And `sudo cat /etc/cryptab' returns:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=41826f3b-d376-4e1e-9ce6-0370b1b9969d /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

It looks to me like the configuration is correct which I why I assume it's a NVMe specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Startup asks for a password to decrypt the swap partition specified in /etc/cryptab. Comment out the line in /etc/cryptab to disable the use of an encrypted swap. The /etc/fstab above is not configured to use /dev/mapper/ctyptswap1 anyway. NVMe should not be a contributing factor.