# 16.04 Swap partition wants password on startup after Gparted resize

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, gparted, cryptswap

Ubuntu new user here. Booted off the 16.04 USB stick last night and used GParted to resize the primary Ubuntu partition - made it larger using some unallocated space.

Now I'm getting a prompt on startup asking for a passphrase. Same type of prompt as was in this question:

[After new Ubuntu 15.04 installation, startup asks for password even though no disk encryption was set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616663/after-new-ubuntu-15-04-installation-startup-asks-for-password-even-though-no-di)

In my case, I do have encryption set up.