# APT asking for Private Key Password?

Tags: 18.04, apt, grub2, upgrade, ssh

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. Sometimes, when I upgrade my packages, APT is asking for a **Private Key Password**. However, if doing nothing, after a few seconds, the upgrade continues normally.

Is it a normal behavior for APT to ask for private key password?

```
~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Calcul de la mise à jour... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  grub-common grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub2-common libpcap0.8
  libpcap0.8:i386
7 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 3,552 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [Y/n] 
Réception de :1 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 libpcap0.8 i386 1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.2 [124 kB]
Réception de :2 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpcap0.8 amd64 1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.2 [118 kB]
Réception de :3 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 grub-efi-amd64-signed amd64 1.93.20+2.02-2ubuntu8.18 [300 kB]
Réception de :4 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 grub-efi-amd64 amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.18 [47.9 kB]
Réception de :5 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.18 [656 kB]
Réception de :6 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 grub2-common amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.18 [532 kB]
Réception de :7 http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 grub-common amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.18 [1,774 kB]
3,552 ko réceptionnés en 4s (890 ko/s)   
Préconfiguration des paquets...
(Lecture de la base de données... 494289 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../0-libpcap0.8_1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.2_i386.deb ...
Déconfiguration de libpcap0.8:amd64 (1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.1) ...
Dépaquetage de libpcap0.8:i386 (1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.2) sur (1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.1) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../1-libpcap0.8_1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de libpcap0.8:amd64 (1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.2) sur (1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.1) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../2-grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.93.20+2.02-2ubuntu8.18_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.93.20+2.02-2ubuntu8.18) sur (1.93.19+2.02-2ubuntu8.17) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../3-grub-efi-amd64_2.02-2ubuntu8.18_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de grub-efi-amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.18) sur (2.02-2ubuntu8.17) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../4-grub-efi-amd64-bin_2.02-2ubuntu8.18_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.02-2ubuntu8.18) sur (2.02-2ubuntu8.17) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../5-grub2-common_2.02-2ubuntu8.18_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de grub2-common (2.02-2ubuntu8.18) sur (2.02-2ubuntu8.17) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../6-grub-common_2.02-2ubuntu8.18_amd64.deb ...
Enter Private Key Password: 
Dépaquetage de grub-common (2.02-2ubuntu8.18) sur (2.02-2ubuntu8.17) ...
Paramétrage de grub-common (2.02-2ubuntu8.18) ...
Installation de la nouvelle version du fichier de configuration /etc/grub.d/10_linux ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Paramétrage de libpcap0.8:amd64 (1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.2) ...
Paramétrage de libpcap0.8:i386 (1.8.1-6ubuntu1.18.04.2) ...
Paramétrage de grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.02-2ubuntu8.18) ...
Paramétrage de grub2-common (2.02-2ubuntu8.18) ...
Paramétrage de grub-efi-amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.18) ...
Installation pour la plate-forme x86_64-efi.
Installation terminée, sans erreur.
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Création du fichier de configuration GRUB…
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-112-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-112-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-111-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-111-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
fait
Paramétrage de grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.93.20+2.02-2ubuntu8.18) ...
Installation pour la plate-forme x86_64-efi.
Installation terminée, sans erreur.
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour systemd (237-3ubuntu10.42) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour shim-signed (1.37~18.04.6+15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1) ...
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
~$
```

Comment: Do you need to insert a private key during boot? Like this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/614780/upgrade-to-15-04-now-asks-for-private-key-password-at-boot If so it is the package grub-common that asks this and it takes a few seconds for apt to supply it.

Comment: Yes, during boot a private key is asked. However, I don't enter anything, and after a few seconds, boot continues. Do you know why a private key is asked? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Upgrade to 15.04. Now asks for private key password at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614780/upgrade-to-15-04-now-asks-for-private-key-password-at-boot), I have disabled the autostart option in the openvpn config file (/etc/default/openvpn) with AUTOSTART="none".
Private key is no more asked during boot, then I guess it won't been asked during upgrade either.

Comment: That will be it :) it is a bug that was supposed to be fixed